# "Message failed" with Facebook Comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to implement Facebook Comments on a site - added it a week ago.
However, it's still saying "message failed" when I try to comment.

Nothing seems to be wrong in the Facebook Sharing Debuggger but on the Facebook Open Graph Debugger it says:
"The app (my_app_id) specified in fb:app_id meta tag is not published yet. App attribution will be disabled when shared stories are rendered. Please check the status in the app settings."

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well _did_ you check the status …?

Comment: I can't find anything close to helpful info about the status in Comment Moderation Tool settings which I figure is what they mean with "app settings".

Comment: No, it means the app dashboard.

Comment: Can't find any info from either the "App-based moderation view" or the "Page-based moderation view".

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe i missed to switch it to "Live" under "App Review". It's still not working though, even if the debuggers doesn't show anything weird. Anything else left to do?